# SQL View Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I am trying to make a view that has 6 columns, and each row is the first 3 rows from 2 columns of another table.

For Example:

```
Asset Table
Asset_ID     Asset_Name
1            Kitchen
2            Bathroom
3            Bedroom
4            Bed
5            Knife
6            Basement

View Combined
Asset_ID_A   Asset_Name_A   Asset_ID_B   Asset_Name_B   Asset_ID_C   Asset_Name_C
1            Kitchen        2            Bathroom       3            Bedroom
4            Bed            5            Knife          6            Basement
```

Is something like this possible?

Sorry, this is purely SQL. I shouldn't have said report.

As for which columns, it will be column X and Y from sql table Z.

Comment: Views and reports are unrelated; which are you trying to do?

Comment: At first blush this looks like a PIVOT, but it's not.  Most reporting software allows you to display data like this in the report specification.  It's extremely complicated to do in pure SQL because it's de-normalizing your data.  The language was built *not* to do that.

Comment: Do you only have those rows? Or do you want the first third, then the second third and then the last third?

Comment: Just added some notes about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me be clear here: this is a *really bad idea* to do this in SQL. That said, it's entirely possible:

```
WITH Ordered As (
    select Asset_ID, Asset_Name, row_number() over (order by Asset_ID) as Sequence
    from Asset
)
SELECT o1.Asset_ID Asset_ID_A, o1.Asset_Name Asset_Name_A
      ,o2.Asset_ID Asset_ID_B, o2.Asset_Name Asset_Name_B
      ,o3.Asset_ID Asset_ID_C, o3.Asset_Name Asset_Name_C
FROM Ordered o1
LEFT JOIN Ordered o2 ON o2.Sequence = o1.Sequence + 1
LEFT JOIN Ordered o3 ON o3.Sequence = o1.Sequence + 2
WHERE o1.Sequence % 3 = 1
```

Comment: Well, I thank you very much both for the warning and the code. I do realize it's a bad idea, but I have my hands tied for certain things and the other options is to build it manually in code with data tables. I figured this one might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. 
First, you need to numbering each row. After that, recursive join some table using row number mod 3 and equals with 0, 1 and 2.

Ps: sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 6 rows

```
SELECT 
    t1.Asset_ID as Asset_ID_A,   
    t1.Asset_Name as Asset_Name_A,   
    t2.Asset_ID as Asset_ID_B,   
    t2.Asset_Name as Asset_Name_B,   
    t3.Asset_ID as Asset_ID_C, 
    t3.Asset_Name as Asset_Name_C
FROM yourtable t1
INNER JOIN yourtable t2
ON t2.Asset_ID  - 1 = t1.Asset_ID 
INNER JOIN yourtable t3
ON t3.Asset_ID  - 1 = t2.Asset_ID 
WHERE t1.Asset_ID in (1,4)
```